# Nativescript RadListView Load on Demand request fails

Tags: nativescript

onLoadMoreItemsRequested is not fired after an api query :

I am pulling data asynchronously with an api query for ListView items. After the loading is done onLoadMoreItemsRequested is never called.On the contrary, If I work with the local database it works fine.

I follow the [NS documents](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/RadListView/load-on-demand) but it looks like I am missing something.

Comment: Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Ok, i will try @Manoj

Other thing is it keeps requesting even if I use :

listView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished(true);

Comment: I found a work around [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/595#issuecomment-378345454) that work for me for now.